# How do I download a youtube video in iOS

Tags: ios, download, youtube

I know how to launch a youtube video within an iOS web view, but how can I download that video to save on my iPad app? Is it possible? Do I need to use some call with a NSURLConnection object and then save the received data into the proper file format?

One specific point I am unsure about is what the url to request the file would be. When viewing a video on youtube, the downloadable videos are triggered with a button, so it's not evident to me what the url would be.

Comment: I think this is against YouTube terms of use

Comment: I am strictly interested in videos that have been set as being allowed to be downloaded. In fact, strictly my own videos. Would this still violate their terms, or is there simply no api/url call to download these?

Comment: @Joey Did you solve this? I have the similar requirement and lost it  how to download youtube videos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to download an iOS-compatible version of the video, possibly using the same technique employed by the [Safari FlashToHTML5 plugin](http://www.joris-vervuurt.com/page9/page9.php).

Youtube DOES offer video download links:

http://lifehacker.com/#!5152236/youtube-offers-official-downloads-and-purchases-for-videos

.. make sure you do not violate their TOS.

In general, when downloading large files, you might consider implementing [resumable file downloads](http://surgeworksmobile.com/iphone/how-to-implement-resumable-file-downloads-on-iphone-sdk), especially because connectivity on a mobile device is transient.

On top of that, make sure that you're on a wifi network when downloading (or resuming a download), using [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). Note that excessive bandwidth usage over cellular networks is a reason for app rejection.

Comment: Great info. One thing I am still uncertain about is how I would even issue the request for a video that is marked as being ok to download. Is there some standard http request that incorporates the youtube video id?

Comment: @Joey: I would suggest that you use the ASIHTTPRequest library (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#downloading_the_response_directly_to_a_file) to download the response directly to a file. Their web pages are full of examples and clear howtos.

Comment: Ok. Do you know what the format of the video download link would be? I notice the download is offered on the youtube page as a button, so the url is not readily obvious.

Comment: @Joey Did you solve your problem? I have the similiar task and searching for a solution now. Thank you.