# how to get YouTube Video URL

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, youtube

I am looking for Youtube Downloader app .and to download Video Firstly I need to get the URL of the Running video.How do I get the url of the video which i play.

but when I play any video into the simulator it automatically gives me some information of the url..which is

```
2013-02-21 12:25:26.518 MyTube[682:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Enabling autoplay
2013-02-21 12:25:26.518 MyTube[682:14003] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 0, on player: 1)
2013-02-21 12:25:26.518 MyTube[682:14003] setting movie path: http://r19---sn-a5m7lner.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?mt=1361429411&ipbits=8&fexp=919113%2C927902%2C916716%2C916612%2C901447%2C902545%2C920704%2C912806%2C902000%2C922403%2C922405%2C929901%2C913605%2C925006%2C906938%2C931202%2C908529%2C920201%2C930101%2C926403%2C901451&newshard=yes&key=yt1&signature=2AB1FC44B4EDA0C5DDF4E715FDCA19FFB16E0FF7.732382C58B3C8CBC4840D462940DFE2FEC9FBE53&source=youtube&sver=3&mv=m&expire=1361452937&ms=au&itag=36&el=watch&dnc=1&cp=U0hVRlRQUF9IUUNONV9MSlRKOjVNc1BwWTUxSVR2&upn=r3oQUqMCths&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&ip=117.215.128.101&app=youtube_mobile&ratebypass=yes&yms=0PtNsY21DUs&id=2a147a30c3da7601
```

that means `setting movie path` url which I needed ..but it comes automatically in the output ..do can i fetch this url ...so that I can download

I am just Playing youtube video into the Webview

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://m.youtube.com"]]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the YouTube API to fetch the URL. Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=de) and [here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/02/youtube-apis-iphone-cool-mobile-apps.html)

Answer (score 1):

Youtube is a little bit tricky in iOS because it's doesn't provide the real video link that obvisioulsy. 
There is a good plugin clalled [LBYoutubeView](https://github.com/larcus94/LBYouTubeView) which handles to extract the real url for you. You can have a look at the link extractor if you just want to download the video...

Another opportunity is to use the [gdata objective c](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/) client and and import the extracted link in an UIWebView. But keep in mind that the `gdata` client doesn't provide you with the real link like the framework above.

And be aware, that UIWebivews in simulators < `6.0` probably `do not` support playing a youtube video in a UIWebview.

At least here is an example of how to embed a youtube video directly in an UIWebView:

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/", @"THEYOUTUBEID"]]]];
```

Comment: LBYoutubeView extracts the url just to make it compatible with MPMoviePlayer, to play video in webview you don't need to extract any! have you checked how the extracted url looks like? If not, try it .

Comment: @MilKyWaY That's what I've said, you do not neccessarily need the real url, but if you want to download it, you do need the real url - did you read the question?

Comment: ok thanks now suppose i got the link which is `http://r19---sn-a5m7lner.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?mt=1361429411&ipbits=8&fexp=919113%2C927902%2C916716%2C916612%2C901447%2C90%2C926403%2C901451&newshard=yes&key=yt1&signature=2AB1FC44B4EDA0C5DDF4E715FDCA19FFB16E0FF7` now if i download the URL it will give me the name just  as only `videoplayback` ..how do i get the actual name of the video

Comment: I've used gdata to extract all metadata of a video, but you could try to parse it out of the html site directly - which is not that nice btw

Comment: BTW: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5807698/how-do-i-download-a-youtube-video-in-ios

Comment: ok if you look at this..https://github.com/iosdeveloper/MyTube there is no need to embed in UIWebView ..it simply runs in UIWebView... not whts the differennce

Answer (score 0):

You can use HCYoutubeParser:
https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser

```
NSString *videoUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", videoId];
NSDictionary *videos = [HCYoutubeParser h264videosWithYoutubeURL:[NSURL URLWithString:videoUrl]];
videoUrl = videos[@"small"];
```